# Flutter Push Notification not working in foreground on IOS above IOS 10

Tags: flutter

here is my code example I found the problem but don't know how to replace
this and working for all above IOS 10 or all

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidRecieveLocalNotification);///HERE IS THE PROBLEM I THINK
var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
_firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(MyConstants.ClientName);
```

**the onDidReceiveLocalNotification is work in foreground when IOS version is 10 or lower then IOS 10**

this is **_firebaseMessaging.configure** code is below

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print('on message ${message}');
    displayNotification(message);

    if (message['data']['bit'] == '1') {
      ShowAlertNotifiaction(context, message['data']['title'], message['data']['body']);
    } else {}
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print('on resume $message');
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print('on launch $message');

    if (message['data']['bit'] == '1') {
      onPageChanged(1);
      navigationTapped(1);
    } else {
      onPageChanged(0);
      navigationTapped(0);
    }
  },
);
```

This for permission

```
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
_firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
  print("Settings registered: $settings");
});
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
  assert(token != null);
  print(token);
});
```

**Note This above Code Is inside initState Method**

After that Add attributes and map that in future here is code

```
Future displayNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails('channelid', 'flutterfcm', 'your channel description', importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High);
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  0,
  message['data']['title'],
  message['data']['body'],
  platformChannelSpecifics,
  payload: 'hello',
);}
```

and then Finally showing the notification

```
Future onDidRecieveLocalNotification(int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) => new CupertinoAlertDialog(
    title: new Text(title),
    content: new Text(body),
    actions: [
      CupertinoDialogAction(
        isDefaultAction: true,
        child: new Text('Ok'),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();

          // On select iOS notification
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);}
```

this is my packages detail for notification

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^0.7.1+1
firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1+1
```

Comment: you need to add capabilities  for that  :https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/

Comment: @HardikMehta
already added and also push notification is working fine but the problem is not working when app is foreground  while IOS version is higher then IOS 10

Comment: update your package firebase_messaging: ^11.2.11

Comment: @RohitChaurasiya  - Ok After that ?

Comment: are you listening for push in this method ?   FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
}

Answer (score 0):

Need to set build gradle settings and set the target ios to '10'
in Podfile.

`# platform :ios, '9.0'` remove the # an set it 10.

Then add to

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
```

in ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift

```
Bool {
    
//Add it here
 
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Then set `compileSdkVersion 33` , `minSdkVersion 21` in app level build gradle(android/app/build.gradle)

By the way in some case when the settings like that, but for android emulator works API 31, 33 may not work(this settings for emulator)